# What are my options in choosing a search engine for my Django app?

Tags: database, django, search-engine

I am building a web site in Django where I would need to implement searching through about 5 million records.

Users need to be able to:

- Search by full text on title and body of entry
- Filter on category
- Sort by Votes
- Sort by price.

Is there a search engine which supports all the above inherently and connects well to django ? I've built a similar system before using Sphinx but was not really happy with it's Django integration. Anyone has other suggestion or can convince me that Sphinx is good enough ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) and select your backend.

Comment: Yeah - in our projects we are using **django-haystack** with **Solr** in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need search engine? MySQL has pretty decent [full-text search support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), some other databases probably do too.
The rest of the features you listed are within standard duties of any RDBMS. With proper indexes, it should be fine even for 5 million objects.

Comment: if this was so easy things like Solr and Sphinx wouldn't exist no ?

Comment: @kokoko It ultimately depends on your expectations. MySQL full-text index is probably slower than Lucene, but it's still pretty fast and at the same time simpler to try. I'm just speaking from 'do first - optimize later' standpoint.